# Undefined offset: 0 yii

Tags: php, yii

In the following code I get this error:

> Undefined offset: 0 in C:...\PolizaController.php Line 173

The File contains the following:

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $connection=Yii::app()->db;
        $sql = "SELECT 
            cliente.comp_seguros
            FROM 
            cliente
            WHERE 
            cliente.nit_cliente = '".$model->nit_tomador."';";
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql); 
        $dataReader=$command->query();         
        $rowsCliente=$dataReader->readAll();
        $model->comp_seguros = $rowsCliente[0]['comp_seguros'];
        if(isset($_POST['poliza'])) {
              $colAnterior=$model->nit_tomador;
              $model->attributes=$_POST['poliza'];
              if($model->nit_tomador!=$colAnterior){
                $connection=Yii::app()->db;
                $sql = "SELECT 
                        cliente.contador_polizas+1 as contador_polizas
                        FROM 
                        cliente
                        WHERE 
                        cliente.nit_cliente = '".$model->colegio."';";
                $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);           
                $dataReader=$command->query();         
                $rows=$dataReader->readAll();
                $model->num_carne = $rows[0]['contador_polizas'];
        }
```

Comment: 1. One of you `if`-Blogs doesn't get closed and wich is line 173ß

Comment: post only a fragment of code, the lines 173 is     $ model-> comp_seguros = $ rowsCliente [0] ['comp_seguros'];

Comment: That means your Array `$rowsCliente` is emty; For debuging add `var_dump($rowsCliente);` between Line 172 and 173